# Don't know how to solve Unit Step Function

Tags: laplace-transform

[image]

This is the solution that i found in the solution sheet but i can't seem to know how to get to the step that is in the red rectangle.

Comment: It's just basic algebra - expand everything in the previous line and then collect terms.

Comment: I try but when i expand i can't seem to group it into the one shown above

Comment: Show your working, maybe somebody can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: i expand till this part : 2u(t) - u(t-1)[2+(t-3)]-(t-3)u(t-3) , Now im stuck

Comment: The $-(t-3)$ is wrong and you should be able to simplify $2+(t-3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We started with $$2[u(t) - u(t-1)] + (3 - t)[u(t-1)-u(t-3)].$$

Distributing we get,

\begin{align}
2u(t) - 2u(t-1) + (3 - t)u(t-1)-(3-t)u(t-3) &= 2u(t) - 2u(t-1) + 3u(t-1) - tu(t-1)-(3-t)u(t-3)\\
&=2u(t) + u(t-1)-tu(t-1) -(3 - t)u(t-3)\\
&=2u(t) -(t-1)u(t-1)-(3-t)u(t-3).
\end{align}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now i understand thanks